# delete zero index of listview which populated from database Android

Tags: android, sql, database, listview

My Database class is this, when i call `deleteEntry`, it does not remove 0 index , this is database class method

```
public int deleteEntry(String id)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        //String id=String.valueOf(ID);
        String where="ID=?";

        int numberOFEntriesDeleted= db.delete("TIME", where, new String[]{id}) ;
        Toast.makeText(context, "Number of Entry Deleted Successfully : "+numberOFEntriesDeleted, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return numberOFEntriesDeleted;
    }
```

this is my `onItemClickListener`

```
list_view.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                Log.d("Clicked item id", " " + id);

               // data.remove(id);
                String row = (String.valueOf(id));
                data.deleteEntry(row);
```

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/25328608/1790537

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
//---deletes a particular entry---
public int deleteEntry(String id) 
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return db.delete("TIME", "ID = " + id, null) ;
}
```

By the way, make sure "TIME" is your tablename and you also close the database.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the position instead of an id:

```
list_view.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        Log.d("Clicked item id", " " + id);
        Log.d("Clicked item position", " " + position);
        String row = (String.valueOf(position)); // the change is here
        data.deleteEntry(row);
}
```

After you try this, look at the logs you get and try to figure out which value (id or position) are better. Anyway, I suppose you should store the database ID of each item you are displaying somewhere, so that you will not rely only on the position inside your list (once any item is deleted from your table, this will not work) since the ID's will not be sequential.

Answer (score 0):

here is what I did
consider i have two tables and so a dynamic  listview with two items (i.e with a custom adapter)

I delete items by name (You can get the name of a selected item at position

Yourlist.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() { @Override public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long id) {

String str = Yourlist.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString();

//consider i have two tables

//create a table called feedslist with a column called "url" where items (the feeds urls) will be stored

mydb.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS feedslist (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,url varchar);");

//create a table called subtitles list with a column called "name" where items (the feeds names) will be stored

mydb.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS subtitleslist (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,name varchar);");

//this is the method to delete entries
 alert.setPositiveButton(R.string.deleteok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

```
                    @Override

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


                        //on positive click we delete the feed from selected position


                        //we're gonna delete them from the db



                        //using cursor 

                        Cursor cursor =mydb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM feedslist;", null);

                        Cursor cursor2 =mydb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM subtitleslist;", null);


                        String url = "";

                        String name = "";


                        //set url

                        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {


                            while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {


                                //we get items at selected position

                                url = mItems.get(datposition);

                                cursor.moveToNext();

                            }

                            cursor.close();

                        }


                        //set feed name

                        if (cursor2 != null && cursor2.moveToFirst()) {


                            while (!cursor2.isAfterLast()) {


                                //we get items at selected position

                                name = mItems2.get(datposition);

                                cursor2.moveToNext();

                            }

                            cursor2.close();

                        }


                        //set the names of the two tables

                        String table1 = "feedslist";

                        String table2 = "subtitleslist";


                        //set where clause

                        String whereClause_url = "url" + "=?";

                        String whereClause_feed = "name" + "=?";


                        //set the where arguments

                        String[] whereArgs_url = new String[] { String.valueOf(url) };

                        String[] whereArgs_name = new String[] { String.valueOf(name) };


                        //delete 'em all

                        mydb.delete(table1, whereClause_url, whereArgs_url);

                        mydb.delete(table2, whereClause_feed, whereArgs_name);


                        //remove items from the dynamic listview


                        //for url

                        mItems.remove(datposition);


                        //for feed name

                        mItems2.remove(datposition);


                        //and update the dynamic list

                        //don't move this method above the db deletion method or

                        //you'll get javalangindexoutofboundsexception-invalid-index error

                        adapter_dynamic.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        adapter_dynamic.notifyDataSetInvalidated();

                        listfeed.setAdapter(adapter_dynamic);
```

You can see working app here

https://github.com/enricocid/iven-feed-reader