# SQLite "no such column found"

Tags: android, sqlite

I am getting a weird error when trying to run a delete query.

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: ITEMS_LINK (Sqlite code 1): , while compiling: DELETE FROM ITEMS_CONTENT_TABLE WHERE BASE_CATEGORY_NAME=? AND BASE_CATEGORY_SRC_PATH=?, (OS error - 2:No such file or directory)
W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:910)
W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:521)
W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:603)
W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:63)
W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.delete(SQLiteDatabase.java:1759)
```

But as can be noted column `ITEMS_LINK` is not used in the delete query.

```
private boolean deleteChildContentFor(SQLiteDatabase db, String parentCategoryLink, String baseCategoryName, String baseCategorySrcPath)
{
    String columns[] = {ITEMS_LINK};
    String selection = PARENT_CATEGORY_LINK + "=? AND " + BASE_CATEGORY_NAME + "=? AND " + BASE_CATEGORY_SRC_PATH + "=?";
    String selectionArgs[] = {parentCategoryLink.trim(), baseCategoryName.trim(), baseCategorySrcPath.trim()};

    Cursor cursor = db.query(ITEMS_CONTENT_TABLE, columns, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);

    if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        do {
            String itemsLink = cursor.getString(0);
            if (itemsLink != null && !itemsLink.isEmpty()) {
                deleteChildContentFor(db, itemsLink, baseCategoryName, baseCategorySrcPath);
            }
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.close();

    String whereClause = PARENT_CATEGORY_LINK + "=? AND " + BASE_CATEGORY_NAME + "=? AND "
            + BASE_CATEGORY_SRC_PATH + "=?";
    String whereArgs[] = {parentCategoryLink.trim(), baseCategoryName.trim(), baseCategorySrcPath.trim()};
    db.delete(ITEMS_CONTENT_TABLE, whereClause, whereArgs);   // Where the error occurs.
}
```

I've included some statements from before since same `db` is used to run query where a column db is mentioned. (I think it is also worth mentioning that I also tried to close the db and obtained another `writableDatabase` to no avail).

**Running Simple Query**
After a suggestion from @MikeT I tried a simple query

```
String query = "DELETE FROM " + ITEMS_CONTENT_TABLE + " WHERE " + PARENT_CATEGORY_LINK + "='"
            + parentCategoryLink.trim() + "' AND " + BASE_CATEGORY_NAME + "='"
            + baseCategoryName.trim() + "' AND " + BASE_CATEGORY_SRC_PATH + "='" + baseCategorySrcPath.trim() + "';";

Log.d("Query", query);

db.execSQL(query);  //  Error on this line
```

The logged Query

```
D/Query: DELETE FROM ITEMS_CONTENT_TABLE WHERE PARENT_CATEGORY_LINK='_____' AND BASE_CATEGORY_NAME='_____' AND BASE_CATEGORY_SRC_PATH='_____';
```

This gave mostly the same error and stack trace but now `PARENT_CATEGORY_LINK` is included in the error-logged query too, which was previously missing.

```
W/System.err: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: ITEMS_LINK (Sqlite code 1): , while compiling: DELETE FROM ITEMS_CONTENT_TABLE WHERE PARENT_CATEGORY_LINK='_______' AND BASE_CATEGORY_NAME='_______' AND BASE_CATEGORY_SRC_PATH='_______';, (OS error - 2:No such file or directory)
W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:910)
W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:521)
W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:603)
W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:63)
W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1960)
W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1885)
```

Comment: This only occurs on Delete command ? Have you tried to do a Select  query for column you try to delete ? Or maybe you misspelled something ?

Comment: @dimmik yes this only occurs for `delete`. No I have not performed a `SELECT` query but the columns are there just before this method is called another is run which uses the same parameters for the same table and is run successfully. In my code you can see that I have used constant Strings as names of columns and tables and I have implemented the same scheme throughout, so misspelling is not possible.

Comment: Also the logged query (from the error) has all the necessary spaces.

Comment: Please provide a reason for downvote.

Comment: try to look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25328565/android-sqlite-delete-query-not-working maybe it can help you

Comment: Show the complete stack trace, and specify where the line numbers point to.

Comment: @CL. I've added StackTrack from the mentioned line I already mentioned the line where error occurs. I don't suppose you have any idea why I'm downvoted?

Comment: First thing I'd do is temporarily swap to using `rawQuery` building the SQL and writing the final SQL to the log,or inspect it via a breakpoint. That's assuming that you've already tried a Clean project (if not then try this first). Quite obviously somewhere it is getting ITEM_LINKS when trying to compile, so odds on it's coming from your code rather than never-never-land.

Comment: @MikeT thanks for the suggestions, I will try all which I haven't yet. However how you say it didn't come from never-never-land is beyond me. The error clearly states looking for `ITEM_LINK` and later goes on to reveal that `ITEM_LINK` is not even part of the query. Unless by never-never-land you mean the previously run query where `ITEM_LINK` was used.

Comment: never-never land  equates to arbitrarily generated. Now if it complained about @#$%^&* column or some utter garbage, then that would be never-never land stuff :). However noting that you say *The error clearly states looking for ITEM_LINK and later goes on to reveal that ITEM_LINK is not even part of the query*. Perhaps consider why it doesn't mention **PARENT_CATEGORY_LINK=? AND** as being part of the query. It could be a clue.

Comment: @MikeT I tried to run query, still gives the same error. And I also cleaned the project.

Comment: uhhm. Have you tried deleting the App Data or uninstalling the App (i.e. delete the database) and rerunning the App? (if this is possible). perhaps include the database structure in the question, preferable the code used by onCreate to create the tables.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153113/discussion-between-abbas-and-miket).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So just found the reason for the strangest of errors thanks to a discussion with @MikeT who told me to post DB's Schema in the question. While doing that I realized that there was some uncommented suppose-to-be-commented `TRIGGER` attached to `ITEMS_CONTENT_TABLE`.

I am not deleting this question and posting this answer to help if anyone else face this issue.